# Google Cloud Container on VM: The JVM based applications stops saying Port permission error

Tags: docker, playframework, google-cloud-platform

From last one week I am trying to deploy the Play-Scala based web server as docker container in Google Cloud Container Optimised OS directly from image registry. It works fine with port numbers above 1024, but below 1024 the application stops. I have set firewall rules as required, checked run as privileged. But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It depends on what services you want to run on that specific port. Ports up to 1024 are reserved for certain services. Port 80 is set for HTTP, port 23 is set for telnet...etc. Ports above 1024 are custom ports. You can use these ports to your liking. What type of service are you trying to run using ports below 1024?

Comment: It happened when a directly created an instance and then setup docker and ran things using docker. It' works fine if I upload a image in container registry and from there if I create a container using that image.

Comment: Since you are running a web server, I am guessing you are trying to change either the HTTP or HTTPS ports (80, 443). You can change these ports to a port below 1024 if you are running as a super user and if there is nothing listening on the said port. I have found this thread that further explains how you can run a service on a port below 1024: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/allowing-a-user-to-let-listen-to-a-port-below-1024